# how to implement status polling using Rx.Net?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, polling

I have been playing around for 2 days now trying to embrace the realm of Reactive Programming using .Net's Reactive Extensions.

I built a use case of a status polling assuming a dummy web API and a reactive client that polls the status object.

I tried the following code :

```
        // Creates an observable that ticks each 1 second
        var ticksObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));



        // Creates a new observable transforming each tick to a string status requested from the api
        var coldStatusPollerObservable = ticksObservable.Select(tick =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending Request");
            var tsk = client.GetStatus(1); // Http get request to a web api resource (id == 1 just for demo)
            tsk.Wait();
            return tsk.Result;

        }
        );

       // Subscribe and print results on console
       coldStatusPollerObservable.Subscribe(
        status => Console.WriteLine(status), ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        );
```

Everything was just fine and i had the expected output :

```
{"status":"waiting"}
{"status":"running"}
{"status":"running"}
{"status":"running"}
{"status":"ok"}
```

Then I added another constraint which is a random Bad Request returned from the web API.
The problem that occurred is that i couldn't handle the exception properly.
The exception occurs in the *tsk.wait()* and what i expected is that it would only trigger the *onError* action i passed to Subscribe method *( ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message) )*

**Q1: What is the right way to handle exceptions in this case ?
Q2: are there cleaner implementations for polling using Rx.NET ?**

*PS: I am using Rx.NET 3.1.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to avoid using any `.Wait()` blocking calls if you can. Rx comes with an operator designed to work with tasks - `Observable.FromAsync`

So your basic query now becomes:

```
var coldStatusPollerObservable =
    from tick in ticksObservable
    from status in Observable.FromAsync(() => client.GetStatus(1))
    select status;
```

If you want your Console message then do this:

```
var coldStatusPollerObservable =
    from tick in ticksObservable
    from status in Observable.FromAsync(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending Request");
        return client.GetStatus(1);
    })
    select status;
```

Just remember to always try to stick with the built-in operators where possible.

---

You can handle exceptions like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var coldStatusPollerObservable =
        from tick in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
        from status in
            Observable
                .FromAsync(() => client.GetStatus(1))
                .Catch<string, Exception>(ex => Observable.Return("Error"))
        select status;

    coldStatusPollerObservable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x), ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));
}

public static class client
{
    private static int _counter = 0;
    public static Task<string> GetStatus(int id)
    {
        if (_counter++ == 5)
            throw new Exception();
        return Task.Run(() => _counter.ToString());
    }
}
```

This gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Error
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
...
```

Comment: Good comments on refactoring the async-call. But how does it affect Exception handling in the Observable?

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks for the help.
Just to mention that the object.Dump() extension method is specific to LINQ pad.

Comment: @AnisTissaoui - Thank you. I removed the `.Dump()` calls.